# Finding a point between intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

When doing the exercise of finding a line between two intersection of planes, we require to find a point and direction vector of the line. The direction vector is easy because it's perpendicular to both the normals, but I'm a tad-bit confused about how to take the point.

Suppose, we were to be given equation of two planes,

$$P_1 : A_1 x + B_1 y +C_1 z+ D = 0$$

And,

$$ P_2  :  A_2 x +B_2 y +C_2 z +D = 0$$

To find a point along the line of intersection, it is often instructed to put one of the coordinates as zero, say $x, y$ or $z$ and then solve for the remaining coordinates. But, I'm not sure why we do this, as in , how do we know that the line between intersection of two lines would always need to have $x$ , $y$ and $z$ intercepts?

I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107156/a-point-on-the-line-of-intersection-of-two-planes) but didn't think it addressed my query and neither was it addressed in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2851908/why-cant-we-find-the-intersection-line-of-two-planes-just-by-using-algebra)

Comment: It won't necessarily have $x,y$ **and** $z$ intercepts, but it will necessarily have an $x,y$ **or** $z$ intercept.

Comment: How would one prove this?

Comment: @DDD4C4U you wont need a rigourous proof for that, the line maybe parallel to a plane hence eliminating intercepts either on x,y or z

Comment: Do you have some knowledge about matrix calculus?  Then it is not too difficult to explain what is going on.

Comment: Mhm yes, I think I know a thing or two

Comment: Vectorially, a line can't be parallel to the three basic planes: it would be orthogonal to the three (linearly independent) normal vectors of these planes.

Comment: hmm I'll have to think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\left|\begin{matrix} A_1&B_1 \\ A_2 & B_2\end{matrix}\right| = A_1B_2-B_1A_2\neq 0$. Then you may reformulate the problem as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_1&B_1 \\ A_2 & B_2\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} 
= -\begin{pmatrix} C_1 z + D_1 \\ C_2 z+D_2\end{pmatrix} 
$$
and solve for $x$ and $y$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} 
= -\begin{pmatrix} C'_1 z + D'_1 \\ C'_2 z+D'_2\end{pmatrix} 
$$
This shows that for any $z=t\in{\Bbb R}$ you get a unique solution for $x$ and $y$. What happens here is that the intersection of the two planes $P_1,P_2$  with the plane $z-t=0$ provides two non-parallel lines (because of the non-zero A-B determinant) in the $x-y$ plane. These two lines therefore have a unique intersection point.

Now, when your A-B determinant above is zero (so your two lines in the $x-y$ plane are parallel) then you may look for a non-zero $B-C$ matrix (and solve for $y,z$) or a non-zero $C-A$ matrix (and solve for $z,x$). If all these determinants are zero then your two original planes are in fact parallel so either the intersection is empty or it is a plane.

Note that the three determinants you compute are in fact the component of the cross-product of normal vectors for the planes, so the cross-product being non-vanishing is indeed a condition for the intersection to be a line.

Answer (score 1):

One might solve the such questions either by assuming any of $(x,y,z)$ to be zero, or keeping one as a constant. The intuition behind keeping one of them zero is that, most of the times the lines we get are not parallel to a plane so they must definitely intersect.

When it's not such a case, keeping the variable zero would yield inconsistent pair of linear equations.